# JS Module vs Script Load Order, Global Variables in Safari

Tags: javascript, module, safari, global-variables

I have been developing a program in Chrome and Firefox, but I noticed that when loading in Safari, I would get errors in the console indicating that certain variables were unavailable.
I have a couple of module script tags in my index.html, whereas the rest are regular script tags.

My first question is whether the modules and scripts are loaded in an undefined order, which might cause part of the issue.

The second thing I noticed:
In my code I use an old-fashioned style pattern in the regular scripts:

```
const NAMESPACE = (function() { const out = {}; ... return out; }());
```

In Chrome and Firefox, this is fine, but it looks like in Safari I need to do:

```
window.NAMESPACE = (function() { const out = {}; ... return out; }());
```

or the console reports an error in other files that says the variable is undeclared in other files. This is even the case for global scope functions and classes!

My second question is: why is this the case? Is there a way to work around this? Could the error only be happening because I am trying to access a variable from a module, and Safari's JavaScript engine doesn't expose global objects to the global scope if you're loading from a module? Somehow I doubt this because the issue persists even when two non-module scripts try to access global scope objects.

What would be the simplest way to resolve the issue? Some third-party scripts cannot be modules. If part of the issue is load order, how can I ensure that a script isn't loaded until another one is available? My thought is to use dynamic imports.